# Fatal error: Class 'GDS\Gateway' not found in datastore.php on line 2

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I was trying to test this [Google Datastore Library for PHP](https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds). I have copied the GDS folder to my application's root directory and created a php file in the same root directory. When i run the code I'm getting this error `Fatal error: Class 'GDS\Gateway' not found in /home/personal/SampleApp/datastore.php on line 2`

datastore.php

```
<?php
    $obj_client = GDS\Gateway::createGoogleClient('AppID', 'xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com', 'appKeyFile.p12');
    $obj_gateway = new GDS\Gateway($obj_client, 'AppID');
    $obj_book_store = new GDS\Store($obj_gateway, 'Book');

    $obj_book = new GDS\Entity();
    $obj_book->title = 'Romeo and Juliet';
    $obj_book->author = 'William Shakespeare';
    $obj_book->isbn = '1840224339';

    $obj_book_store->upsert($obj_book);
?>
```

Is there anything I'm missing here ?

Comment: Did you include the class files in the script? i.e. `require("path/to/your/classes/");`

Answer (score 1):

Did you use composer to pull in the library? If not you'll need to either write your own autoload script or add the following lines

```
include_once 'src/GDS/Entity.php';
include_once 'src/GDS/Gateway.php';
include_once 'src/GDS/Store.php';
```

Comment: Thanks @Mars. But now i'm getting this error: `Fatal error: Class 'Google_Client' not found in GDS/Gateway.php on line 90`

Comment: GDS itself has dependency on google api client so it's best to use composer to generate the autoloader script. Otherwise, you can manually download the lib from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client and include its autoload.php before GDS.